# Coffeescript Ajax -- can't get variable to work outside of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coffeescript

So i have this coffeescript function:

```
thestring = ""
$.get '/ajax/questions', (data) -> 
    counter = 0
    dataLength = data.length
    while counter < dataLength
        thestring += "<option value=test>it wont work</option>"
        counter++   

console.log(thestring)
$("#question"+(numfilters+1)).append thestring
```

in my case, data is an array of arrays of length 2, (ex: [[hello,test],[hi,moretest]] ). The problem seems to be that my variable, "thestring", is only changed locally inside the function. When I attempt to log what the value is, i simply get whatever i initially assigned it (in this case the empty string). What I'm trying to do here is append options to a dynamically generated select box based on the data received from the ajax request.

Comment: `$.get` is an async function - you need a callback! You're trying to log `thestring` before the call has finished. Also, ditch that `while` loop and use `for` loop.

Comment: any reason why for loops are better? I used js2.coffee to translate a javascript for loop and for some reason it turned it into a while loop in the coffeescript.

Comment: I suppose it's just preference - but typically `while` loops are used for reading data from a file - your data has a set end (the length) - so a `for` seems more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an asynchronous function, so the code inside the callback will be set aside to be executed *after* the ajax request completes, and the rest of the top level function completes first. Just move your code for handling the result inside of the callback function:

```
thestring = ""
$.get '/ajax/questions', (data) ->
    # The code here will be run *after* the ajax function completes
    # This is called a callback 
    counter = 0
    dataLength = data.length
    while counter < dataLength
        thestring += "<option value=test>it wont work</option>"
        counter++   

    console.log(thestring)
    $("#question"+(numfilters+1)).append thestring

# Any code after here will execute immediately 
#  (i.e., before the ajax function completes)
# So if you access `thestring` here, it will still be empty
console.log thestring
```

Comment: Ah! makes sense. However, for some reason i can't append to the select box variable inside the callback scope. Any reason why this might happen?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "can't"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: By can't I mean that nothing happens when i put the append jquery inside the callback. I get no errors thrown but no options are added. I know that it is not because "thestring" is empty, because i check it right before i append it with console.log and it always logs the correct string. Is this a problem with scopes?

Comment: @DanielCiotoli can you log `console.log $("#question"+(numfilters+1))` to ensure you're actually selecting the correct element?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why it wasn't appending to the select box. The variable "numfilters" was getting increased before it was evaluated in the asynchronous call. To solve this i assigned a new variable called "jaxfilters" right before the asynchronous call, which takes whatever value that numfilters has and is not increased.